# Laravel Pages with Categories Route Parameters

Tags: php, laravel

based on the example from here https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-and-easy-laravel-routing#blog-pages-with-categories-route-parameters

I want to show entries for specific categories.
By calling this Route:

```
Route::get('menues/{city?}', 'PagesController@menue');
```

I want to show all entries for a specific city.

This is my Controller:

```
public function menue($city = null) {

  if ($city) {
    $restaurants = User::with(['articles' => function ($q){
        $q->nowpublished();
    }])->where('city', '=', $city)->get();
  } else {
    $restaurants = User::with(['articles' => function ($q){
        $q->nowpublished();
    }])->where('city', '!=', $city)->get();
  }

  return view('pages.menues')
    ->withRestaurants($restaurants) 
    ->withCity($city);
}
```

The only thing that doesn't work is, by calling a url with a `{city}` that doesn't exist in the DB I want to display all entries. 
With the code above this doesn't happen. I get a blank page.

How can I fix this? My guess was that the code inside my else statement displays all entries, but this isn't the case.

Comment: Are you passing an id? `{city}` is the ID of the city?

Comment: city is a string. http://localhost:8000/menues/london or http://localhost:8000/menues/lasvegas

Comment: Did you put this route inside and group if yes please also share that group route ? If there is also a route variable then in your controller function first variable would be group route variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
public function menue($city = null) {
    $restaurants = User::with(['articles' => function ($q){
        $q->nowpublished();
    }]);

    if(if(!is_null($city) && !is_null(City::where('name', $city)->first())) {
        $restaurants->where('city', '=', $city);
    }

    $restaurants = $restaurants->get();
    return view('pages.menues')
        ->withRestaurants($restaurants) 
        ->withCity($city);
}
```

`->where('city', '!=', $city)` is the problem. If you want to get all articles, remove the condition.

Change the condition to:

`if(!is_null($city) && !is_null(City::where('name', $city)->first())`

Comment: Also same result, I only get entries for existing cities, but not all entries if a city doesn't exist.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Also don't forget to change the column in `where()` to match your column in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Use Requests $request

```
 public function menue(Request $request) {
   if ($request->has('city')) {
```

Comment: still a blank page without all entries

Comment: It should be `$request->has('city')` :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
public function menue($city = null) {
  if ($city) {
    $restaurants = User::with(['articles' => function ($q){
        $q->nowpublished();
    }])->where('city', '=', $city)->get();
    if (restaurants->count() == 0) {
        $restaurants = User::with(['articles' => function ($q){
            $q->nowpublished();
        }])->get();
    }
  } else {
    $restaurants = User::with(['articles' => function ($q){
        $q->nowpublished();
    }])->where('city', '!=', $city)->get();
  }

  return view('pages.menues')
    ->withRestaurants($restaurants) 
    ->withCity($city);
}
```

Comment: That's wrong on so many levels. Especially, because you are executing way more queries than needed.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Ok. I just misunderstood the question.